# How to know the state of the shipping address in magento programmatically?

Tags: php, magento

I am writing the following code in magento.

```
$orderId = '100000023';
        $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($orderId);
        $billingAddress = $order->getBillingAddress();
        $shippingAddress = $order->getShippingAddress();
        print_r($billingAddress);
```

Now If I want the state of shipping what is the GET function to be used(if any). If not function what is the way to get the state of shipping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Region is variable name in magento for state of address You can get it :

```
    $orderId = '100000023';
    $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($orderId);
    $billingAddress = $order->getBillingAddress();
    $shippingAddress = $order->getShippingAddress();
    echo $shippingAddress->getRegion();
```

if you want to get region id then get it with:

```
<?php echo $shippingAddress->getRegionId();?>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to see all data from some model (in this case shipping address), just use debug() method in combination with Zend_Debug to dump everything:

```
$orderId = '100000023';
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($orderId);
$billingAddress = $order->getBillingAddress();
$shippingAddress = $order->getShippingAddress();

Zend_Debug::dump($shippingAddress->debug());
```

you should get something like:

```
array(13) {
  ["entity_id"] => string(1) "2"
  ["parent_id"] => string(1) "1"
  ["region_id"] => string(2) "15"
  ["region"] => string(8) "Delaware"
  ["postcode"] => string(6) "12345"
  ["lastname"] => string(3) "Musterman"
  ["street"] => string(5) "Main Street"
  ["city"] => string(4) "Newark"
  ["email"] => string(13) "someemail@gmail.com"
  ["telephone"] => string(6) "234324"
  ["country_id"] => string(2) "US"
  ["firstname"] => string(3) "Max"
  ["address_type"] => string(8) "shipping"
}
```

and you can get all these data by:

```
$shippingAddress->getEntityId();
$shippingAddress->getParentId();
$shippingAddress->getRegionId();
$shippingAddress->getRegion();
...
```